# Having trouble instantiating players on network

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm trying to make a pretty simple multiplayer platforming type game.  Until recently I had only the main scene which would automatically create or join a fixed room.  All players who ran the game would auto join and instantiate, everything at this point worked properly.

Now I'm trying to add in a title scene with the ability to create a personal room or join an existing one. Upon creating/joining a room you are then moved to the main scene that I'd been using before. This works with one glaring issue. Players that joined before you do not show up for you.  Anybody that joins after you is visible, and you are visible to any who joined before you.


in the main scene after you've joined the room your character is instantiated with:

```
PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPrefabName,
                          spawnPoint.position,
                          Quaternion.identity,
                          0);
```

So all players currently in game should be instantiated on the network and thus in your game, why is this not the case?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I ended up solving my own problem (answer below). I'll leave the question open for another 24 hours or so in case someone has a better solution or a reason why my solution is bad, after that I'll mark my answer the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my own problem. The solution I came up with was to pass (via a global static) the name of the room to create/join and then in the new scene's NetworkManager use it to create/join the room. This seemed to fix my issue